# ASP.NET MVC jQuery UI Checkboxradio tick disapear after checked

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I'm doing an ASP.NET MVC website. Which needs a feature let admin set if the membership of each clubs member joined are valid still.
After a bit survey, I figure [jQuery UI Checkboxradio](https://jqueryui.com/checkboxradio/) quite fit my demand.

When I check the checkbox it seems fine, ticked and the background becomes blue.
However, when I move the mouse out the tick disappears while the background remains blue.

[image]

Then if I move the mouse over it, the tick will show up again but only when the cursor remains on the widget.

I check the post value of viewmodel which is correct and if I comment

```
//$("input[type=checkbox]").checkboxradio();
```

The original checkboxes work as expected.(tick won't disapear)
So I think it should be a frontend problem.

Here is the part of my View

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClubMultiChosen.Clubs, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ClubMultiChosen.SelectedClubs.Count; i++)
        {
            var memberships = Model.ClubMultiChosen.SelectedClubs;
            @Html.Label(@memberships[i].Club.Abbr, new { @for = $"cbxClub{i}" })
            @Html.CheckBox($"ClubMultiChosen.SelectedClubs[{i}].IsActive",
                @memberships[i].IsActive, new { id = $"cbxClub{i}" });
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

At the same page I have included
bootstrap 3.3.7
bootstrap-chosen 1.0.0
jQuery 3.1.1
jQuery UI 1.12.1
And My mvc version is 5.2.3.0

Not sure if I provided enough info. Any suggestion or question will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

For some reason when it is checked(`class=ui-state-active`). It uses ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png as background which is **white** yet the background of checkbox(span) is white as well, so it looks like the tick was disappeared.

After I override it with

```
#form1 .ui-state-active .ui-icon, 
#form1 .ui-button:active .ui-icon {
    background-image: url("/Content/themes/base/images/ui-icons_555555_256x240.png");
}
```

It works as I expected.